# Nested Transactions Exception although synchronized methods and error handling

Tags: javascript, hibernate, jsp, servlets, transactions

I am developing a Java-Web Application using Hibernate -> MySQL.

A user sees a JSP page, it calls controllers to get data from DB, also it has a Javascript function which fetches larger data strings via ajax.

**The problem:**
When the user refreshes the page right after loading the page, the servlet responsible for the ajax data throws this exception:
org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported

I believe this gets caused by a transaction from the first call, which is still active when the user refreshes and the second call gets executed.

I marked every controller method with hibernate interaction as **synchronized**.
Now the user is able to refresh 1-5 times, but then the exception **still occurs**.

I am using Hibernate 4.3.1.

HibernateUtil.openSession() is just sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

This is the controller-snippet where the exception occurs:

```
public static synchronized Widget getWidgetById(long id) {
    Widget result;
    Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
    try {
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        try {
            result = (Widget) session.get(Widget.class, id);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            tx.rollback();
            throw ex;
        }
    } finally {
        //disabled since we use transaction.auto_close_session
        //session.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Are there any mistakes that I didnt see?
What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Opening a hibernate session in the controller is not proper implementation for hibernate. You should be separating your hibernate session into a service layer or even further a data access layer. You call this controller to open the JSP, which opens a hibernate session. Then your ajax request calls the same controller and tries to open an additional hibernate session, but you already have one open thus giving you the nested transaction exception. This will always happen if you leave the hibernate session logic in the controller. You should reconsider your design of the application.